# How to setup KVM partitioning?

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to install SolusVM/KVM on a server with one 500 GB HD and one 256 SSD. I am a complete beginner at Linux. SolusVM has a script on the site to download and install automatically, but how do I specify to install the script on the 500 GB HD and put the virtual machines on the SSD? And how should my partitioning look like? I want KVM isos and stuff on HD and virtual machines on SSD. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just let the SolusVM install run, when you create the volume group, just create it on your SSD and define the volume group in the Administrator panel.

The ISO's are stored in `/home/solusvm/xen/iso` (`/home/solusvm/kvm/iso` is simply a symlink to `/home/solusvm/xen/iso`).

Comment: Thanks! But how should I partition the drives? And how do I install the SolusVM on the 500 GB HD?

Comment: @Richard Have a look at: http://docs.solusvm.com/installation#partitioning. You just install SolusVM as described in the installation Wiki **but** when you need to create the volumegroup, create it on the SSD ;-)